# Getting Form Input Values From JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using Materialize to create a select form in my html. How do you store the input value from this form using a variable in javascript/jquery?

This html code for the form is:

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
function jsFunction(){
var e = document.getElementById("ViewSelect");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(strUser)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <select id="ViewSelect" onchange="jsFunction()">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

You should have ID to your Select Statment

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
      <select id="ViewSelect">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

Then You Should access in JavaScript as

```
var e = document.getElementById("ViewSelect");
var optionSelectedIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var optionSelectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. how would you recommend passing in this value into a GET request when you change your selection on the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can get selected value and text by jquery like this:

```
$("select option:selected").val(); //to get value
$("select option:selected").text(); // to get text
```

and if you have more than one select on your page,you have to add an id for each select element.

for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#materializeSelect").change(function(){
   getValue();
});
});


function getValue(){
alert('Value is: ' + $("#materializeSelect option:selected").val()); //to get value
alert('Text is: ' + $("#materializeSelect option:selected").text()); // to get text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="materializeSelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment under @Batman's answer this might help you.

This is mostly jQuery and you don't need to use a function to keep calling the same code base for different selector's just use a selector class as shown in my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.materializeSelect', function() {
    var selVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),
      selTxt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if (selVal !== "" && selTxt !== "") {
      window.location.href = "yourphppage.php?val=" + selVal + "&txt=" + selTxt;
    } else {
      alert("Select a material");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select class="materializeSelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label><br/>
  <select class="materializeSelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/r1edyopm/)